# May a Jew Benefit from non-Toiveled utensils

Tags: halacha, gentiles, tevilas-keilim-dipping, yoreh-deah, hanaah-benefit

According to Halacha, is it permissible for a Jew to benefit from selling non-Toiveled utensils to non-Jews or no? For example, if Jews decide to buy up the rights to a silverware company that sells silverware made from non-Jews, without Toiveling, would that be fine (if the customers are non-Jews)? Or are non-Toiveled utensils that Jews own similar to chametz on Passover which they can’t benefit from?

Comment: Beth Yosef 120:8 citing Mahiri Berabh permits merchants to sell items that haven't been immersed. This is widely accepted in practice to my observation. It is debated whether restaurants may rely on this BY or not.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14214/759 Business inventory is plausibly not even obligated in this mitzva.

Comment: See SA YD 120:8 and nose kelim thereon.