Tevilla for second hand dishes
I heard once that if a Jew, who is trustworthy in halacha, gives you their second hand dishes, which they definitely tovelled themselves, you still have to tovel them again.
I was young and impressionable then, but having learned the halachot myself, I never saw this concept, and can't make sense of it. I would just like to double check if anyone else knows of this idea and if they have a source.
Thank you

Perhaps they were referring to a new dish that they never used. Like a present. The Halacha is one shouldn’t give a present without toiveling first, but in modern times most people don’t do that.

@Chatzkel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14214/759

AFAIK complete error on that person's part. (It happens.)
